# Add section title progress meter to PowerPoint slides

Tags: powerpoint, presentation, google-slides

I am designing a presentation in PowerPoint. One feature I miss from LaTeX/beamer, though, is the ability to have a progress bar, showing what section of the presentation you're in:
[image: LaTeX slide with progress meter highlighted]

I am looking for a solution in PowerPoint, using VBA if necessary, to show a "progress meter" that displays all of the sections, with the current section highlighted. Similar functionality is standard in LaTeX/beamer.

Is it possible to (dynamically) create this functionality in PowerPoint? (I guess I'm also open to Google Slides.)

The only relevant result I've found is this, but it's too simplistic. It’s only a progress  bar, without section titles or anything: https://www.howtogeek.com/709523/how-to-create-a-progress-bar-in-microsoft-powerpoint/

Comment: You mention that the example is too simplistic, but don't say in what way? You need to be more specific. The image you posted is too low-resolution/blurry to make any sense of.

Comment: Added an explanation

Comment: Where? I don't see it here. Sorry.

Comment: I explained that the link just shows how to add a progress bar, but not how to add section titles or anything. The image is just a standard beamer slide. None of the details are relevant.

Comment: After this line in the linked macro:  s.Name = "PB", add a new line, s.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "whatever you like"

Comment: Not sure what you mean, exactly. If you could write out a full answer, I  would really appreciate it.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service, but if you want to have a go at writing it  yourself, we'll be happy to help debug/improve whatever you come up with.

Comment: I’m not asking for a “code-writing service.” I’m asking for a viable example that I can build off of.

Comment: >> " If you could write out a full answer ..."  No, afraid not.  Again, start with the example in the link you posted, add the line I suggested, see how far you can take it on your own. Post your code back here when you hit a wall. Be sure to indicate what it's not doing that it should, what it's doing that it shouldn't and quote the exact text of any error messages you get and what line you get them on.